# Random encounter to the exception : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, exception

I am running selenium WebDriver suite having 35 test cases using TestNG framework.
FF 32.0.1 and Selenium 2.44.0. Eclipse Indigo is being used.

In a day atleast 2- 3 times i am stuck with the below exception when i run my script.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary

But rest of the time my script runs perfectly fine. Firefox will launch instantly. 
But when the above exception is encountered then for quite sometime i am stuck and i need to wait , keep trying until firefox starts again. I am not able to find out why it randomly keeps giving this exception. sometimes i close all the browser and using task manager Ends the process and wait.

Please give me a permanent solution for this as i m not facing this situation always.

Regards

Comment: Could somebody please help me in this issue !!

Comment: Can somebody please suggest me about this issue.